# closing a server after listening crashes with Not running exception

Tags: node.js

i have the following code:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
    console.log("request");
});
console.log("== 1");
server.listen(8124, 'localhost',function(){console.log("listening");});
console.log("== 2");
server.close();
```

the output is:
`== 1`
`== 2`
and then the net module throws the exception of `Not running`.
in the node.js docs it's written that:
`Stops the server from accepting new connections. This function is asynchronous, the server is finally closed when the server emits a 'close' event.`
if it's asynchronous then why do i get that output? it should listen first and then close it.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee that server will start listening before you close it (because listening is asynchronous).

Closing the server like:

```
server.listen(8124, 'localhost', function () {
  console.log("listening");
  server.close();
});
```

should work.

Comment: is there a way to ask if the server had started listening?

Comment: Yes. Listening server has non-null `server._handle`, but it's an internal API. You should wait for a callback.